# The click event of jetpack compose version 1.5.0 fails

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

1. Problem Description:
   When I upgraded Compose BOM to version 20230800, `clickable` occasionally did not take effect. When I rolled back to version 20230601, it worked fine again.
2. Compose: `platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.06.01')`

3.Reproduce path: This ComposeView is added in the form of `WindowManager.addView`.

4. The following is a code snippet:

[image: code]

5. Video:

[image: video]

I try to reduce the compose version to `2023.06.01`, and the phenomenon will return to normal。 Looking forward to help from the Compose development team。

Comment: It's even worse for me - after updating to 1.5.0 the previous button gets the click event. For example I have a simple keyboard layout, when I touch top left button, then bottom right, the top left is clicked again (both visually and firing onClick)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be a bug in Compose 1.5.

After comparing, I found that when adding a view to the WindowManager, if it's the first time, touch works normally. But after hiding it and adding the view again, touch becomes invalid.

A temporary solution is to create a new ComposeView every time addView is called.

Comment: Additionally, be aware that if you use other Compose libraries, such as accompanist-systemuicontroller > 0.30.1, they may also pull in Compose 1.5 and introduce this bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can add these code snippet and your issue will be solved. [more](https://gist.github.com/handstandsam/6ecff2f39da72c0b38c07aa80bbb5a2f?permalink_comment_id=3654582#gistcomment-3654582).

```kotlin
val coroutineContext = AndroidUiDispatcher.CurrentThread
val runRecomposeScope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)
val recomposer = Recomposer(coroutineContext)

composeView.compositionContext = recomposer
runRecomposeScope.launch {
    recomposer.runRecomposeAndApplyChanges()
}
```